# question about markov chain with the states

Tags: probability-theory

[image]

If I understand correctly, this can be used as the definition of transient/recurrent state.

but I need help to start please guide me to solve

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is easy to see that all the negative numbers are transient since for any $k<0, P(k,0) > 0$ and after you reach $0$ it is impossible to ever hit a negative number again.

Clearly $0$ is recurrent since no matter where you are you have positive probability of immediately going to $0$.

Similarly, from any $k_0$ and any $k>0$ the probability that your next $k+1$ moves are $k_0\to 0 \to 1 \to \cdots \to k$ is bounded in probability strictly above $0$. Here we are using the fact that anything that always has a reasonable chance of happening will almost surely happen, sooner rather than later. Formally if $\tau$ is a stopping time and there exists $k$ such that for all $n$ we have $P(\tau \leq n + k | \mathcal{F}_n) \geq \epsilon > 0$ then $E[\tau] < \infty$ and in particular $P(\tau < \infty) = 1$.

Comment: you said all negative are transient ,0 is recurrent, what about positive numbers? I did not understand your last paragraph, can u explain a little bit more

Comment: Please don't link to outside images. Revert back to my edit. $k>0$ is positive. I'm saying that for any positive number, the probability that you return to that number is $1$ because the expected amount of time to return to the number is finite. The expected amount of time to return to the number is finite because no matter where you start from, it is possible to jump to $0$, then to $1$, then to $2$ and so on until $k$, and this sequence occurs with probability $P(k_0,0)P(0,1)\cdots P(k,k+1) > 0$.

Comment: just have to confirm again, positive numbers are also recurrent as well as 0, correct?

Comment: Yes, that is correct.